# How to prevent pivot table from resizing after refreshing data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have slicers and pivot tables on a single sheet and would like to preserve the pivot table size after refreshing the data. Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Comment: What happens if the new data can't fit in a table this size, or conversely if it would only fill a smaller pivot table?

Comment: Do you mean want to keep blank cells after filtering so that the Table Size is not changed? How about adding new data into the PivotTable? If my understanding is correct, your requirement is not available.

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting that can be changed in Pivot Table Options > Layout and Format. Uncheck "Autofit Column Widths on Update".

Believe this should help you. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. **To avoid resizing of Slicer** > Right Click on Active Slicer > Position and Layout > Diable Resizing and moving.

[image: marked screenshot of format slicer]

2. **To avoid resizing of Pivot Table** > Layout and Format. Uncheck "Autofit Column Widths on Update". You can permanently off it by doing the same option in Default pivot layout

Comment: "You can permanently off it by doing the same option in Default pivot layout" => could you elaborate on this. Today is the day I unchecked that option for the 1000th time, and I'm on a crusade to permanently disable this stupid option. :)

Answer (score 0):

To **permanently** turn off autofit you have to update the default pivot layout:

File>More Options>Options>Data>Edit Default Layout>PivotTableOptions>Layout &  Format then uncheck the box next to "Autofit column widths on update"

I'm still new so I can't post images but the link shows where to look under the options menu https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhicw.png